# Order columns individually in R

Tags: r

I am after reshaping the data, and get the below, see screenshot. How can I push the values up? Such that column 2 b row 5, value b, will go into column 2, element 1? Like removing the ID vector and pushing the remaining data upwwards.

I have tried d <- apply(d, 2, sort) and it does not work.

```
structure(list(ID = 1:17, a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), e = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), r = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), g = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: provide data, not image

Comment: Any easy way to paste in data? sorry working for 7 hour on this...

Comment: just copy paste the data the way it is or simply run `dput(data)` copy the results and paste that here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it the easiest approach is to convert into a list and remove the blanks, and then put the list back together as a data frame.

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:17, a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), e = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), r = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), g = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

dat2 <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(dat)) {             # Using for-loop to add columns to list
  x <- dat[ , i]
  
  x <- x[!is.na(x)] #remove the blanks
  x <- c(x, rep("", nrow(dat)-length(x))) #make new blanks after the values of interest, as to have equal rows to original
    
  dat2[[i]] <-x
  
}


res<-data.frame(do.call("cbind", dat2)) #from list to dataframe
names(res) <- names(dat) #put in original names
```

with the other data structure (very similar)

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1:17),
                  "1" = c(rep("a", 4), rep("", 13)),
                  "2" = c(rep("", 4), rep("b", 5), rep("", 8)),
                  "3" = c(rep("", 9), "c", rep("", 7)),
                  "4" = c(rep("", 10), "d", rep("", 6)),
                  "5" = c(rep("", 11), "e", rep("", 5)),
                  "6" = c(rep("", 12), "f", rep("", 4)),
                  "7" = c(rep("", 13), rep("g", 4)))

dat2 <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(dat)) {             # Using for-loop to add columns to list
  x <- dat[ , i]
  
  x <- x[x != ""] #remove the blanks
  x <- c(x, rep("", nrow(dat)-length(x))) #make new blanks after the values of interest, as to have equal rows to original
  
  dat2[[i]] <-x
  
}


res<-data.frame(do.call("cbind", dat2)) #from list to dataframe
names(res) <- names(dat) #put in original names
```

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately, it does not work in Alteryx, since I am running R through this application, but works perfect in R! It converts the text to numbers, and ultimately does not structure the data how it is intended to be structured...

Comment: I think there might be some stuff with "NA" vs. "".  and the text to numbers appears to be from your "dput". There is at least a difference in between your screenshot and example data. I have edited to fit both

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na.last = TRUE`. See `?sort`

```
apply(d, 2, sort, na.last = TRUE)


##>       ID  a  b  c  d  e  r  g
##>  [1,]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
##>  [2,]  2  1  2 NA NA NA NA  7
##>  [3,]  3  1  2 NA NA NA NA  7
##>  [4,]  4  1  2 NA NA NA NA  7
##>  [5,]  5 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA
##>  [6,]  6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##>  [7,]  7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##>  [8,]  8 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##>  [9,]  9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [10,] 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [11,] 11 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [12,] 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [13,] 13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [14,] 14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [15,] 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [16,] 16 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##> [17,] 17 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to filter out each NA, then resize the vectors:

```
raw <- structure(list(ID = 1:17, a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
               d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 
                     NA, NA, NA, NA), e = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                            NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), r = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), g = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                          7L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
library(tidyverse)

lapply(1:length(raw), function(i){
  tmp <- raw[i] %>% filter(!is.na(.)) %>% pull() #filter NA
  length(tmp) <- nrow(raw) #resize to length of raw struct
  tmp #return
}) -> res

tbl <- res %>% bind_cols() #make table
colnames(tbl) <- raw %>% colnames() #set old column names
tbl
```

Stefanos solution should be preferred though